# Why is Vue.js not printing an object property even though it exists?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this in my template:

```
<div v-if="errors && errors.name" class="text-danger">{{ errors.name[0] }}</div>
```

And in the component, I definitely have the `errors` object defined, it has a `name` property and that property's value is an array of strings. From dev tools:

[image: vue dev tools]

Why is the string in the first array member of `errors.name` not showing then? It looks like the condition `errors && errors.name` is never true but I can't tell why. I've tried using `errors.hasOwnProperty('name')` instead but to no avail.

Comment: How do you set the error? Remember vues reactivity quirks with arrays.

Comment: `this.errors['name'] = ["Please enter a name."];`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats and `properties in data are only reactive if they existed when the instance was created`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add properties to an object on the fly as Michal mentioned in the comment.

```
data: function () {
  return {
    errors: {
      name: []
    }
  }
}
```

And then with arrays, you cannot assign values directly, use the push method instead and as you initialize it with the above code, you already have an array:

```
errors.name.push('Please enter a name.');
```

And lastly in the template, only check the length, as the object is now sure to be present:

```
<div v-if="errors.name.length > 0" class="text-danger">{{ errors.name[0] }}</div>
```